# How to stretch png image to cell width and keep correct cell/height ratio

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table with 4 cells evenly split across 80% width of screen.
My png files display correctly but are not filling the cells width so it looks bad.

I want the height stretching to maintain ratio. How can i do this? I know i can put height-100% and width=100% into each img but how do i use css to do same? .styleObj width and height doesnt seem to affect it.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .styleTbl
    {
        margin-bottom:10%;
        margin-left:10%;        
        background: #aeaeae;
        width:80%;

    }
    .styleCol
    {
        background: #ffffff;
    }
    .styleRow
    {
        background: #000000;
    }
    .styleBg
    {
        background: #00aced;

    }
    .style_logo
    {
        width:80%;
    }
    .styleObj
    {
        height:100%;
            width:100%;
    }
    </style>
    <link href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

```
<img alt="logo_banner Missing" class="style_logo" longdesc="Banner" src="logo_banner.png"/>
<br />
<table class="styleTbl">
    <tr class="styleRow">
        <td class="styleObj">
            <object data=index.html></object></td>
        <td class="styleObj">
            <img alt="png" longdesc="png1" src="png1.png"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="styleRow">
        <td class="styleObj">
            <img alt="png1" longdesc="png1" src="png1.png"/></td>
        <td class="styleObj">
            <img alt="png1" longdesc="png1" src="png1.png"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ahh i realise why this did not appear to work the first time but raises a second question. When i put width and height into my css style it doesnt work, when i put it directly into each img it does. Why?         

.styleObj
        {
         height:100%;
         width:100%
        }

Comment: and also not set height to `100%` but rather to `auto`

Comment: Not sure what you mean '.styleObj img'? I put class="styleObj" and it doesnt work!

Comment: Add this to your css - `.styleObj img{width: 100%;}`

Comment: Good stuff. I do=idnt know i had to explicitly say img - why is this?

Comment: Oh and can you rite an answer below and i will tick as solution. Thanks/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qRxJB/

**CSS**
Add this

```
 .styleObj img{
       width: 100%;
  }
```

Also, remove this:

```
.styleObj
{
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
}
```